# How to extract data from ELF files recovered by Photorec?

Tags: data-recovery, photorec

I recovered all the files from a partition by using Photorec. Now I have thousands of recup_dir.* directories containing thousands of f*.elf files.

How can I extract the data from all the *.elf files?

Edit: I did not understand correctly. The .elf files seem to be executable files that I had in the partition. They are not the type of data I am looking for.

Comment: Hello. More info is needed. What version of Ubuntu? Why did you use this 4 or 5 year old recovery software? What did you expect it to do? https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec

Comment: Hello. I am using 20.04.4 LTS. I used Photorec because I did not know any other software for this purpose. I expected to recover my files at the original format instead of as ELF files.

Comment: You still have not explained why you needed to so this.

Comment: I removed all the files from that partition by accident and I need to recover them. My files were .tex, .txt, .pdf, .png, etc.. . I have now recovered them by using Photorec, but as .elf files. I need to convert the .elf files into the original extensions.

Comment: When I looked at the info for this app it says for recovering photos. I would suggest looking for some support from the makers of the app. Really has noting to do with the Ubuntu OS.

Comment: Check if they really are ELF files, the `.elf` extension is meaningless. Use `file f*.elf`.

Comment: I have used Photorec & it recovered all my text files. It just also recovered the old deleted ones and I have 4 or 5 copies of some of them. Lots of grepping & comparing to an old backup to try to see which was most current. It should not have recovered .elf files unless those were just executable files. Do you have another folder with .txt files? http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step